# Create unique relationship in neo4j

Tags: java, neo4j, cypher, spring-data-neo4j

I want to create unique relationship in neo4j. My requirement is , i have a common resource for all nodes, so if node A is using it, then node B cannot use it, means cannot create relationship of B with resource. So how can i do this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure at the moment you can't have neo4j enforce for you.  I think you would need to check whenever you try to add the relationship.  Here's an example in cypher, though if you're using java you might be using a lower level API:

```
MATCH (a:LabelA {id: '123abc'), (res:Resource {id: '321cba'})
  WHERE NOT(()-[:has_resource]->res)
  CREATE a-[:has_resource]->res
```

Comment: I've since learned about (though haven't used) `TransactionEventHandler` which lets you write java code to have event handlers.  See http://neo4j.com/api_docs/1.4/org/neo4j/graphdb/event/TransactionEventHandler.html